# Updating the index in an SQL database (python)

Tags: sql, python-3.x, tkinter

while creating a tkinter application to store book information, I realize that simply deleting a row of information from the SQL database does not update the indexes. Kinda hard to explain but here is a picture of what I meant:
[link to picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjdR1.png) (still young on this account, so pictures can't be embedded, sorry for the inconvenience)

As you can see, the first column represents the index and index 3 is missing because I deleted it. Is there a way such that upon deleting a row, anything below it just shifts up to cover for the empty spot?

Comment: Does the index come from database records?

Comment: @acw1668 yes it does, the backend uses this : `cursor.execute("DELETE FROM lib WHERE id = ?", (id,))`.

Comment: If it is from database, it cannot be changed as it is the unique ID to identify the record in database.

Comment: @acw1668 that makes sense, thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of the word "index" must be based on the application language, not the database language.  In databases, indexes are additional data structures that speed certain operations on tables.

You are referring to an "id" column, presumably one that is defined automatically as `identity`, `auto_increment`, `serial`, or whatever the underlying database uses.

A very important point is that deleting a row from a table *does not affect other rows in the table* (unless you have gone through the work of writing triggers to make that happen).  It just deletes the rows.

The second more important point is that you do not want to change the "identity" of rows -- and that is what the column you are calling an "index" is doing.  It identifies the row.  It not only identifies the row today, but it identifies the same row tomorrow.  And, if it existed, yesterday.  That is, you don't want to change the identity.

This is even more important when you have foreign key relationships -- that is, other tables that refer to this row.  Those relationships could get all messed up if the ids start changing.

SQL does offer a simple way to get a number with no gaps:

```
select row_number() over (order by "index") as seqnum
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the extremely thorough explanation! I initially thought that the database would be in the form of an excel spreadsheet so the idea of an index did come to mind, but you have made it clear that what I am using as part of my code is the unique identification of that entry!